# Elliptic integral as inverse of Weierstrass elliptic function

Tags: complex-analysis

My textbook writes

$
\wp^{-1}(w) = \int^{w} \frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\sqrt{4w^3 - g_2w - g_3}} 
$

and simply states that this shows that $\wp(z)$ is the inverse of an elliptic integral.
But how is the integral above an elliptic integral? I've tried looking at the three kinds and they don't seem to match the form of this integral

Comment: The Wikipedia article [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) defines an elliptic integral as $\,\int_c^x R(t,\sqrt{P(t)})\, dt\,$ where $\,R\,$ is a rational function of its two arguments, $\,P\,$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ or $4$. In the integral you mention $\,P\,$ is of degree $3$.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from $$\wp'(z)^2=4\wp(z)^3-g_2 \wp(z)-g_3$$ (which itself follows from the definition of $\wp=\wp_\tau$ and that elliptic functions with no poles are constant)

and $(\wp^{-1}(w))'=\frac1{\wp'(\wp^{-1}(w))}$ that $$\wp^{-1}(w)= \wp^{-1}(w_0)+\int_{w_0}^w \frac{dw}{\sqrt{4w^3-g_2 w-g_3}} $$
You can let $w_0\to \infty$ and set $\wp^{-1}(\infty)=0$.
All this is "up to choosing the right branch of $\wp^{-1}$ and $\sqrt{}$".

Then taking a root $a$ of $4w^3-g_2 w-g_3$ you get $4(w+a)^3-g_2 (w+a)-g_3=w(w-b)(w-c)$ so that
$$\wp^{-1}(w)= \int_\infty^{w-a} \frac{dw}{\sqrt{4 w (w-b)(w-c)}}
$$ $$
=\int_\infty^{\sqrt{w-a}} \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2-b)(u^2-c)}}
=\int_\infty^{\sqrt{(w-a)/b}} \frac{du}{\sqrt{c (1-u^2)(1-\frac{b}c u^2)}}
$$
which is an incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind